# How do I document objects referring to a type in an object literal?

Tags: javascript, class, visual-studio-code, namespaces, jsdoc

I have the following scenario:

```
var myNamespace = {
    /**
     * @type {myNamespace.MyClass|undefined}
     */
    myObject: undefined,

    MyClass: class MyClass {
    },

    MyOtherClass: class MyOtherClass {
        /**
         * @type {myNamespace.MyClass}
         */
        myProperty
    }
}
```

Is it possible to document this in a way to make visual studio code can give me suggestions, without using @typedef, and if so, how would I go about it?

I have tried various different formats, but every time the result is the same where I get "Type  = /*unresolved*/ any".
Both inside and outside of the namespace the result seems to be the same.

I would be ok with documenting the object ("myNamespace") in complex detail, but it would still refer to types inside of itself, which I doubt is possible?